# Can I make a DataGrid in WPF which is bound to SQL update automatically when the SQL Table changes?

Tags: sql, wpf

I have a DataGrid which is populated from SQL.
When I insert an entry I would like the DataGrid to automatically update the table to include the new entry.

Should I just call my "PopulateFromSQL" function again or is there some kind of callback / trigger I can use?
Calling the "PopulateFromSQL" function would mean I would have to call it from another Window, is this bad practise?

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is 'no'. There is no any way to know either sql table or any row in it was updated. The only way is to query the table rows. If your app is multiuser app, any user can change rows in table, so it would be not enough just to trigger your insertion. I think it would be better to refresh your table each time you make changes. You can achieve it through events or by using EventAggregator pattern. You also can call it from another window. It's not so bad, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to be notify by the database using **MSSQL Event broker** system

Here's: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

When you trigger a table update, then update your **DataGrid**